# Facebook API: Suggest page to friends and view which are were selected

Tags: facebook

I am developing an application which is based on user challenges. The app also requires a Facebook account to play.

I want a user to be able to select a bunch of friends he wants to challenge and send them an "invitation". But besides this, I need to find which friends did the user invite in order to save them to my database and "prepare" the challenge.

I managed to do the select-friends-dialog using [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/), but have no idea how to retrieve the selected users. Also, does this work on non-canvas Facebook applications? As I read that page, I am not sure whether it will work for my non-canvas application.

Here is my select-friends-dialog code:

```
function challengeFriends(){
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'message",
    title: 'title'
});
```

}

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a tutorial that covers what you are asking for and other aspects of the [Request dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/): [How To: Send An Application Request Using The Facebook Graph API](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-send-an-application-request-using-the-facebook-graph-api/44/)

The idea is to capture the request ids from the callback and save them in your DB, and within the request itself you can find the invitee id (friend id):

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Check out this application!',
    title: 'Send your friends an application request',
},
function (response) {
    if (response && response.request_ids) {
        var requests = response.request_ids.join(',');
        $.post('handle_requests.php',{uid: <?php echo $uid; ?>, request_ids: requests},function(resp) {
        });
    } else {
        alert('canceled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your tutorials are exactly what I need!